# ODatabasePool has no relation to OPartitionedDatabasePool

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB 3 ; manual kicks off talking about `OrientDb` & `ODatabasePool`

However anyone using `OPartitionedDatabasePool` cannot move freely to `ODatabasePool`. Though their names imply some resemblance they have none.

Not able to understand the design intent, since  ideally switching between the two should be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

They have some resemblances between each other however you need to take a few steps more if you want to use the latter.

Here's some info from the OPartitionedDatabasePool documentation:

`To acquire connection from the pool call acquire() method but to release connection you just need to call ODatabase.close() method.`

[OrientDB Javadoc | ODatabasePool](https://orientdb.com/javadoc/develop/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/ODatabasePool.html)

[OrientDB Javadoc | OPartitionedDatabasePool](https://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/OPartitionedDatabasePool.html)